# Not sure if I can force www, remove extensions, keep query strings, and route it all through the index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Well for a while I have been using codeigniter, but with the appeance of noone ever buying it. I don't see it being continued as far as development. That said, I am breaking away finally and wanting to go back to my roots so to speak, and hone in some of my skills. However I am unfortunately not that great with htaccess rules, and I became spoiled by codeigniter handling it for me with a couple lines of like below

```
#Removes index from url
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|temp_pix|assets|qrgen|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

What I want to do, is push everything through the index.php similar to your normal MVC/CMS.
If its not a valid file/directory. I want to then assume its But I do not want php/html/htm showing up in the URL. I'd also like to keep using query strings on occasion ie: `domain.com/something/?foo=bar&bazz=who_knows`. I also want to force trailing slashes when applicable, and force www

Now I have been digging for a bit and attempting combination after combination but I haven't come up with anything that really works

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess should take care of all of your requirements:

```
# to support extension-less URIs
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# to enforce www in domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# to enforce trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# internal rewrite to send all non files/directories to index.php as a query
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```